# последнее действие в while

Tags: php

Каким образом можно поставить точку в конце действий while вместо запятой?

```
$a = 1;
$b = mt_rand(1,10); 
while ($a <= $b) {
    echo $a;
    echo ", ";
    $a++;
}
```

Код выше это пример, на самом деле у меня в while листает массив.

Comment: проверить что $==$b и поставить точку вместо запятой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

```
$a = 1;
$b = mt_rand(1,10);
while ($a <= $b) {
    echo $a;
    echo ($a != $b ?", ":'.');
    $a++;
}
```

**Вариант 2**

```
$a = 1;
$b = mt_rand(1,10);
$result = array();
while ($a <= $b) {
    $result[] = $a++;
}
echo implode(', ', $result).'.';
```

**Вариант 3**

```
$a = 1;
$b = mt_rand(1,10);
echo implode(', ', range($a, $b)).'.';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 1;
$b = mt_rand(1,10); 
while ($a <= $b) {
    echo $a;
    if($a != $b){
        echo ", ";
    }else{
        echo ".";
    }
    $a++;
}
```